# Setting a number of decimal places a GeoJSON will have when pulled from PostgreSQL db

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geometry, react

I have noticed that the markers on my Leaflet map are displaying slightly off and I believe this is being caused by the GeoJSON coordinates only pulling to 4 decimal places. I can see this by looking an the console log coordinates that are being displayed.

Is there any way for me to set the number of decimal places the GeoJSON should include?

I have them stored in a PostgreSQL db to about 8 places so that shouldn't be the problem.

map.component

```
export class ScubaDivingMap extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            schoolList: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        pullScubaSchools().then((response) => {
            const { data } = response;
            this.setState({ schoolList: data.data });
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.schoolList.length > 0) {
            console.log("list", this.state.schoolList);
        }

        let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: icon,
            shadowUrl: iconShadow,
        });

        return(
            <container maxWidth="sm">
            <div>
                <Typography
                    component="h1"
                    variant="h2"
                    align="center"
                    color="textPrimary"
                    gutterBottom
                >
                    Diving School Map
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    variant="h5"
                    align="center"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    paragraph
                >
                    List of approved Sustainable Scuba diving schools offering our courses and recommended by our staff.
                </Typography>
                <container>
                <MapContainer
                    center={{ lat: 41.505, lng: -0.09 }}
                    zoom={3}
                    scrollWheelZoom={false}
                >
                    <GeoJSON
                        //style={this.countryStyle}
                        data={pullScubaSchools.diveSchoolGeo}
                        //L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(pullScubaSchools.diveSchoolGeo)
                        //onEachFeature={this.onEachCountry}
                    />
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    {this.state.schoolList.length > 0 &&
                    this.state.schoolList.map(({ diveSchoolGeo }) => {
                        console.log("diveSchoolGeo", diveSchoolGeo.coordinates);
                        return (
                            <Marker position={[diveSchoolGeo["coordinates"][1], diveSchoolGeo["coordinates"][0]]} icon={DefaultIcon}>
                                <Popup>
                                    {diveSchoolGeo}
                                </Popup>
                            </Marker>
                        );
                    })}
                </MapContainer>
                </container>
            </div>
            </container>
        );
    }
}

export default ScubaDivingMap;
```

console.log of Geojson coordinates

```
Array [ 27.9117, 34.3324 ]
 
Array [ 18.9553, 69.6492 ]
 
Array [ 142.7285, 46.9641 ]
 
Array [ 46.8691, -18.7669 ]
 
Array [ 167.5954, -15.4493 ]
 
Array [ 95.3192, 5.8942 ]
 
Array [ 80.217, 6.0367 ]

Array [ 95.3192, 5.8942 ]
 
Array [ -5.9594, 54.6798 ]

Array [ 170.4631, -45.8966 ]
 
Array [ 23.3645, -34.0575 ]
 
Array [ -155.8282, 20.0353 ]
 
Array [ 48.2593, -13.315 ]
 
Array [ -87.4654, 20.2114 ]
```

I am not 100% sure it is the shortened coordinates that are causing the problem as all of the markers are displaying below were they should be.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you mean by "the GeoJSON coordinates only pulling to 4 decimal places". Client side or server side?

Comment: When the array is rendered client-side it only seems to be the coordinates to 4 decimal places. All the different markers seem to be about 1 / 1.5 cm south of where they should be so it could be something else.

Comment: But what do you get from server? And what do you mean by "1 / 1.5 cm south". On the real terrain or on the map? If on the map, at which zoom?

Comment: Those array coordinates are what comes up in the web console when I console.log.

Comment: Then this is what you get from server, so it's server related problem.